# nested if statements javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, each

I'm trying to do a lookup until i found an especific value; currently using if statements like this but right now its only two levels and i dont need how many if statements will be needed until the conditions meets.

```
if (newObject.parent.toString() != 1) {
            alert(newObject.shareholder + ' no es 1 Buscaremos sus padres');
            var newObject = parentSearch.search(newObject.parent.toString())[0].item;

            if (newObject.parent.toString() != 1) {

                var newObject = parentSearch.search(newObject.parent.toString())[0].item;

            } else {
                alert(newObject.shareholder + ' Found');

            }
        } else {
            alert(newObject.shareholder + ' Found');

        }
```

Is there a way to avoid using infinite IF statements ?

Comment: please add your data. what is `newObject.parent.toString() != 1` doing?

Comment: use recursion, make a function and call it recursively until base condition is met.

Comment: `toString()` returns a string, why are you comparing it with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of recursion as follow:

```js
function checkObject(newObject) {
    if (newObject.parent.toString() != 1) {
        alert(newObject.shareholder + ' no es 1 Buscaremos sus padres');
        const newObject = parentSearch.search(newObject.parent.toString())[0].item;

        checkObject(newObject)  // recursion
    } else {
        alert(newObject.shareholder + ' Found');

    }
}
```

In case you cannot use recursion, you can use following:

```js
function checkObject(newObject) { 
    while (true){
        if (newObject.parent.toString() != 1) {
            alert(newObject.shareholder + ' no es 1 Buscaremos sus padres');
            
            newObject = parentSearch.search(newObject.parent.toString())[0].item;
        } else {
            alert(newObject.shareholder + ' Found');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check JSONPath for that deep lookup : https://jsonpath.com/.

It allows you to make a string query and execute it on an object and returns fields that match the query.